# Showing the limit of a sup

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and suppose that $g(x)=\sup \left(f(t)\right)$ for $t>x$.
Show that $\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) = g(a)$ for all real $a$.

I'm not sure how to start this.
Do we want to show that $\limsup f(t) = g(a)$?
If so, is it possible to say that since we are evaluating a right sided limit, we then want to find a $\sup f(a^+)$ since $a^+>a$ which is then $g(a)$ since $g(x)=\sup \left(f(t)\right)$?
How can I write this more concretely?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552538/show-that-lim-x-to-a-gx-ga Is there a take-home analysis test due tomorrow?

Comment: @ZachL. That's not the only time - this is the fourth time I've seen the question recently.

Comment: @ZachL That or a homework is due.